# C# group list by time interval

Tags: c#, .net

I want to group my data based on a given time interval like 1m, 1h, 1d etc..

```
 var tables = await query.QueryAsync(flux, "AAE");
            return tables.SelectMany(table =>
                table.Records.Select(record =>
                    new MachineDataModel
                    {
                        result = record.GetValueByKey("result").ToString(),
                        table = int.Parse(record.GetValueByKey("table").ToString()),
                        _start = record.GetValueByKey("_start").ToString(),
                        _stop = record.GetValueByKey("_stop").ToString(),
                        _time = record.GetValueByKey("_time").ToString(),
                        _value = int.Parse(record.GetValueByKey("_value").ToString()),
                        _field = record.GetValueByKey("_field").ToString(),
                        _measurement = record.GetValueByKey("_measurement").ToString(),
                        end_time_str = record.GetValueByKey("end_time_str").ToString(),
                        machine = record.GetValueByKey("machine").ToString(),
                        start_time_str = record.GetValueByKey("start_time_str").ToString(),
                    }));
        });

        returnModel.MachineList = results.ToList();
```

I want to group the data that is in the returnModel.MachineList by a given interval. I have no idea how to do this.

Comment: Have you tried using Modulo Operator `%`? Depending on the type of `_time` (milliseconds, DateTime, ...) you could calculate the remainder and then sort your collection by that value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you haven't provided the data model, I assumed...

```
class MachineDataModel
{
    public DateTime _start; //can also be parsed from '_start_time_str'
    public DateTime _end; //can also be parsed from '_end_time_str'
    //..some more....
}
```

You can Group Elements by a minute interval with:

```
var GroupByMinutesList = list.GroupBy(x => (x._end - x._start).Minutes);
//replace 'Minutes' with 'Hours', 'Days', etc...
```

To convert it to a dictionary simply:

```
var GroupedByMinutesDictionary = GroupByMinutesList.ToDictionary(x => x.Key.ToString() + " minute(s)", x => x.ToList());
```

the above dictionary will give you:

```json
{
   "1 minute(s)": 
   [{
      myMachineDataModel object
   }],
   "2 minute(s)":
   [{
     myMachineDataModel object
   }]
   etc...
}
```

**The Test Data I used**

```
List<MachineDataModel> list = new()
{
    new MachineDataModel
    {
        _start = DateTime.Now,
        _end = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30)
    },
    new MachineDataModel
    {
        _start = DateTime.Now,
        _end = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(90)
    },
    new MachineDataModel
    {
        _start = DateTime.Now,
        _end = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(45)
    },
    new MachineDataModel
    {
        _start = DateTime.Now,
        _end = DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(75)
    }
};
```

Result:

```
//JsonConvert.SerializeObject(GroupedByMinutesDictionary)
{
  "0 minute(s)": [
    {
      "_start": "2022-01-19T10:47:03.2527701+05:00",
      "_end": "2022-01-19T10:47:33.2527733+05:00"
    },
    {
      "_start": "2022-01-19T10:47:03.2528154+05:00",
      "_end": "2022-01-19T10:47:48.2528156+05:00"
    }
  ],
  "1 minute(s)": [
    {
      "_start": "2022-01-19T10:47:03.2528141+05:00",
      "_end": "2022-01-19T10:48:33.2528145+05:00"
    },
    {
      "_start": "2022-01-19T10:47:03.2528158+05:00",
      "_end": "2022-01-19T10:48:18.252816+05:00"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you can parse your _time string to a DateTime, you can use GroupBy like so:

```
Func<DateTime, long> GetIntervalKeyGenerator(Interval interval)
    => interval switch
    {
        Interval.Years => date => date.Year,
        Interval.Days => date => date.Year * 1000 + date.DayOfYear,  
        ...
        _ => throw new NotImplementedException()
    };

Enumerable.Range(1, 1000)
    .Select(i => DateTime.Now + TimeSpan.FromMinutes(i))
    .GroupBy(GetIntervalKeyGenerator(Interval.Hours), date => date);
```